# R: compute correlation by group

Tags: r, correlation

In R, I have a data frame comprising a class label *C* (a factor) and two measurements, *M1* and *M2*. How do I compute the correlation between *M1* and *M2* within each class?

Ideally, I'd get back a data frame with one row for each class and two columns: the class label *C* and the correlation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The package plyr is the way to go.

Here is a simple solution:

```
xx <- data.frame(group = rep(1:4, 100), a = rnorm(400) , b = rnorm(400) )
head(xx)

require(plyr)
func <- function(xx)
{
return(data.frame(COR = cor(xx$a, xx$b)))
}

ddply(xx, .(group), func)
```

The output will be:

```
  group         COR
1     1  0.05152923
2     2 -0.15066838
3     3 -0.04717481
4     4  0.07899114
```

Comment: (+1) Nice `plyr` package, isn't it? :)

Comment: This works great. Thanks for pointing out the plyr package! Could you please explain the ".(group)" syntax?

Comment: aix - sure.  It means "split the data by the variable between .(), and on each subset perform the function".  In order to have it include more variables, you should simply use this syntax:  .(var1, var2, var3) .  Which is like cutting your data by each combination of levels of var1, var2 and var3.  And on each cut to perform your function.  This package is maintained by Hadley (also th author of ggplot2), so I trust it will keep developing.

Comment: Oh, and BTW, you could also use plyr with a parallel computing on several cores (almost automatically), see: http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/09/using-the-plyr-1-2-package-parallel-processing-backend-with-windows/

Comment: @chl - indeed :)

Comment: That's a nice answer, but I'm astonished there isn't a built-in solution for this, something like cor(x, y, by=z) would be so intuitive...

Answer (score 12):

If you are inclined to use functions in the base package, you can use the `by` function, then reassemble the data:

```
xx <- data.frame(group = rep(1:4, 100), a = rnorm(400) , b = rnorm(400) )
head(xx)

# This returns a "by" object
result <- by(xx[,2:3], xx$group, function(x) {cor(x$a, x$b)})

# You get pretty close to what you want if you coerce it into a data frame via a matrix
result.dataframe <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(result))

# Add the group column from the row names
result.dataframe$C <- rownames(result)
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! I've been experimenting with `by`, but couldn't figure out how to transform the result into a data frame.

Answer (score 9):

Another example using base packages and Tal's example data:

```
DataCov <- do.call( rbind, lapply( split(xx, xx$group),
             function(x) data.frame(group=x$group[1], mCov=cov(x$a, x$b)) ) )
```

Comment: Elegant solution Joshue.  Do you think there are cases when one solution is better then another?

Comment: I think it's a matter of preference.  My example is essentially what `plyr` does but it gives you finer control, though it's not nearly as clean.  My opinion would change if one solution had a better time/memory profile.  I haven't compared them though.

Comment: How does this return the correlation?

Answer (score 2):

Using data.table is shorter than dplyr

```
dt <- data.table(xx)
dtCor <- dt[, .(mCor = cor(M1,M2)), by=C]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar method that will give you a table with the n's and p values for each correlation as well (rounded to 3 decimal places for convenience):

```
library(Hmisc)
corrByGroup <- function(xx){
  return(data.frame(cbind(correl = round(rcorr(xx$a, xx$b)$r[1,2], digits=3),
                          n = rcorr(xx$a, xx$b)$n[1,2],
                          pvalue = round(rcorr(xx$a, xx$b)$P[1,2], digits=3))))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more modern solution, using the `dplyr` package (which didn't yet exist when the question was asked):

Construct the input:

```
xx <- data.frame(group = rep(1:4, 100), a = rnorm(400) , b = rnorm(400) )
```

Compute the correlations:

```
library(dplyr)
xx %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(COR=cor(a,b))
```

The output:

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

  group         COR
  (int)       (dbl)
1     1  0.05112400
2     2  0.14203033
3     3 -0.02334135
4     4  0.10626273
```