# How to calculate group statistics in R

Tags: r, correlation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R: compute correlation by group](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4040/r-compute-correlation-by-group)

I have a data set with a 6 or so data points for groups of data.

e.g.:

```
email_id   date_sent  number_sent  number_of_views  number_of_responses
1           5/4         600            25                6
1           5/5         500            22                8
1           5/6         450            23                4
1           5/7         700            34               12
2           5/5         900            30               10
2           5/6         750            28               11
...
```

(this is made up data that illustrates the point)

Assuming I have this in a data frame in R, I'd like to write something which will give me stats by group.  I'm most interested in the correlation coefficient between some of the columns.

I know how to do this with a data frame that contains only one group:

cor(col1, col2)

but I'd like to learn a technique that will allow me to extract data that looks something like this:

```
email_id    cor(col3, col4)
1             .73
2             .85
3             .98
```

and so on.

Thanks,

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4040/12258) and [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/8225/12258). Maybe there should be a community wiki entry for this?

Comment: Quite right, and they have some great answers that I've +1ed.  It'd be nice if there were a a way to know about other *answers*, as one would if asking a new question.

Comment: @Conjugate Unfortunately, I am not aware of such facilities on SE sites. I'm closing this as a duplicate, though your response was on the point here.

Comment: Fine by me.  It is clearly a duplicate.  And borderline stackoverflow in any case.

Answer (score 5):

Assume your data is in `d`.  A fairly transparent and easy to reuse solution to this task is:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(d, "email_id", summarise, corr=cor(number_sent, number_of_views))
```

which will give you a data.frame with `email_id` and `corr` as variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data frame containing your data is called `dat`:

```
aggregate(1:nrow(dat), dat["email_id"], function(idx) {
   c("cor(col2, col3)" = cor(dat[[2]][idx], dat[[3]][idx]),
     "cor(col2, col4)" = cor(dat[[2]][idx], dat[[4]][idx]))
})
```

This should get you started.