# How to check if the correlation between two continous variables is influenced by a categorical factor?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, correlation, interaction, linear-model

I have a data frame (df) where I see correlation between two continuous variables (c1 and c2). I need to know whether the observed correlation between the two variables differs between groups, which are identified with a categorical variable (v1)?

I tried to find interaction using lm function in R. I tried lm(c1~c2*v1,data=df) and looked for p value of the interaction c2:v1. I am not sure if this is correct. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should implement a Sperman correlation (by group).

See [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4040/r-compute-correlation-by-group), to another stackexchange.com question.

In alternative, see [this other link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791650/spearman-correlation-by-group-in-r), to another stackexchange.com question.

Comment: Thank you for those links. But I also need to know if the correlations obtained by factors are statistically different. Any comment on that?

Comment: Doesn't R give you p-values as well? That's what you should look at.

Comment: I meant if I get correlation in subset1 is 0.4 and subset2 is 0.6, I need to know if correlation in subset1 is statistically different from correlation in subset2. Hope you get me.

Comment: Lets say I am looking for the correlation between the blood insulin and glucose levels in a group of participants. Suppose if i need to know how the correlation varies, if i group them in to diabetics and non-diabetics, what should I do.

Comment: I have tried to clarify your question. Roll it back if you do not like it or distort the meaning of your initial question.

Comment: Ok, given what I have understood now, it seems that your initial approach makes sense. One thing though (I am not a doctor), is there any reason to think that  being diabetics per se does not affect C1?

Comment: That is an example I gave, since its well known fact.

Comment: Normally, when you use an interaction in your regression, you should add also the main effects; instead, you would exclude the main effects of v1 or c2 only if you had a very strong reason for doing that. So, probably your command should be: lm(c1~c2*v1 + c2 + v1,data=df). But I am not sure it is the best way of doing that.

Comment: See the previous comment. The coefficient on c2 would give you the effect of c2 on c1 when v1 is 0. When v1 is 1, the total effect of c2 on c1 would be given by the sum of the coefficients on c2 and c2*v1. The coefficient on v1 would give you the effect of v1 on c1. If there was no difference between groups in terms of effect of c2 on c1, the p-value of the interaction effect would have you rejecting the H0.